# Issue with Bean Validation while testing a Spring Controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testng, hibernate-validator, spring-test-mvc

I have a Spring RestController that looks something like this:

```
...
import javax.validation.Valid;
...
@RestController
@RequestMapping( value = "/users", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User add(@RequestBody @Valid User user)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**PS**: **@Valid** next to the User : This is where I have the problem.

This is one of the tests for the controller:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestAppConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private UserController userController;

    @Test
    public void addTest()
    {
       User user = new User();
       ...
       userController.add(user);
       ...
    }
}
```

The TestAppConfig looks something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {Constants.BEANS_BASE_PACKAGE})
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebMvc
class TestAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
}
```

**Problem**: Everything other than `@Valid` works fine (invocation of the service). Here, `@Valid` is `javax.validation.Valid` annotation that I wish to use for simple validations (implementation = Hibernate Bean Validator). However, during my tests, I don't see the Validations happening. They do happen when I invoke the service calls, though. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're invoking `add` method directly on `UserController`, spring is unable to intercept your request and do its validation magic. It's better to use `MockMvc` and perform your requests on it, like following:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestAppConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void addTest()
    {
       User user = new User();
       ...
       mvc.perform(post('/users')
                   .content(...)
                   .contentType(...)
                   .accept(...))
       ...
    }
}
```

see [spring test doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-framework) for more details.